# Не работает блок if в цикле while Python 3.7.2

Tags: python

Почему при первом вводе "quit" моя программа не прерывает цикл[image: введите сюда описание изображения] while? В переменно answer уже сохранено значение "quit", но программа все ровно продолжает цикл while, игнорируя проверку if

```
file = "answer.txt"
active = True
message2 = "do you have any other reasons? (if you wanna to quit press'quit')"
message = "Why do you like programming? (if you wanna to quit press'quit')"
answer = input(message)
while active:
    if answer == "quit":
        active = False
    with open(file, "a") as file_object:
        file_object.write(f"{answer}\n")
    answer = input(message2)
```

Comment: То, что ваш скрипт выдает второе сообщение, еще не значит, что цикл не заканчивается. И блок if как раз отрабатывает. А то, что перед окончанием цикла скрипт  еще и файл успевает прочесть и второй вопрос задать -  ну так именно так и написан скрипт.

Answer (score 1):

Потому что когда вы вводите quit, цикл продолжается, потому что цикл проверяет условие только когда начинается новая итерация. То есть:

Цикл начинается, потому что условие active верно

Вы вводите quit, active становится неверным, но цикл продолжается

вы снова что-то вводите

цикл завершается, потому что условие active неверно

Comment: спасибо за помощь

Answer (score 0):

Как уже подметили выше, Вы после получения строки `quit` продолжаете цикл, записывая в файл ответ и требуя ещё одну строку для завершения цикла, который должен был закончиться ещё раньше.

Если ввод ответа в файл обязателен, то можно избавиться от флага `active`, сделать цикл вечным и прерывать его после ввода `quit`. Перед проверкой, конечно, записываем ответ в файл.

```py
file = "answer.txt"
message2 = "do you have any other reasons? (if you wanna to quit press'quit')"
message = "Why do you like programming? (if you wanna to quit press'quit')"
answer = input(message)
while True:
    with open(file, "a") as file_object:
        file_object.write(f"{answer}\n")
    if answer == "quit":
        break
    answer = input(message2)
```

Comment: Спасибо за то что помогли.

Comment: @kirich в таком случае предлагаю отметить один из ответов как верный, нажав на галочку слева от текста вопроса. Можно дополнительно поставить вопросам +, если нужно :)

Answer (score 0):

Там прежде чем with нужно добавить

```
elif answer != "quit":
    with open(file, "a") as file_object:
        file_object.write(f"{answer}\n")
```

А вообще то не нужно добавить переменную как "active". Лучше пишите так:

```
file = "answer.txt"
message2 = "do you have any other reasons? (if you wanna to quit press'quit'):"
message = "Why do you like programming? (if you wanna to quit press'quit'):"
answer = input(message)
while answer != 'quit':
    with open(file, "a") as file_object:
        file_object.write(f"{answer}\n")
    answer = input(message2)
```